# Quanteda: how to create identically-featured dfms from a list of words

Tags: r, dictionary, text-mining, corpus, quanteda

I run a randomforest on n-gram matrix of articles, because I would like to classify it to 2 categories. As a result of RF I received a list of important variables.

Now I would like to run random forest only on the selected first n features and then use the same features for predicting new classification. For that 
I need to create dfm only for most important variables (from RF). 
How can I create a dictionary from a list of those important variables?

The relevant part of the code... after creating a dictionary I have only one entry in it. How to create it properly?

```
forestModel <-
  randomForest(x =  as.matrix(myStemMat),y=as.factor(classVect),
               ntree = 1000 )

impVariables <-
  data.frame(important = as.matrix(importance(forestModel)))

impVariables <-
  impVariables %>% mutate(impVar = row.names(impVariables)) %>% 
  arrange(desc(MeanDecreaseGini)) %>% 
  top_n(1000, wt = MeanDecreaseGini) %>% 
  select(impVar) %>% as.list() %>% dictionary()

myStemMat <-
  dfm(
    mycorpus,
    dictionary=impVariables,
    #   remove = stopwordsPL,
    stem = TRUE,
    remove_punct = TRUE,
    ngrams=c(1,2)
  )
```

In brief, when I have a list of strings, of words, n-grams, how can I create a dictionary so that I can use it in the `dfm()` function to generate term matrix?

Here is a link to complete code "reproducible example" and data it uses. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3oe1tcfcauer0wf/text_data.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read the `?dictionary` carefully, since this not designed to be a set for feature selection (although it can be), but rather to create equivalence classes among values assigned to dictionary keys.

If your `impVariables` is a character vector of features, then you should be able to use these commands to perform the selection you want:

```
toks <- 
    tokens(mycorpus, remove_punct = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_select(impVariables, padding = TRUE) %>%
    tokens_wordstem() %>%
    tokens_ngrams(n = 1:2)

dfm(toks)
```

where the last command produces a document-feature matrix of just the stemmed, ngram features that were selected in the top features from your random forest model.  Note that the `padding = TRUE` will prevent ngrams from forming that were never adjacent in your original text.  If you don't care about that, set it to `FALSE` (the default).

**ADDED:**

To select the columns of the dfm from a character vector of selection words, here's two methods we can use.

We will work with these sample objects:

```
# two sample texts and their dfm representations
txt1 <- c(d1 = "a b c f g h",
          d2 = "a a c c d f f f")
txt2 <- c(d1 = "c c d f g h",
          d2 = "b b d i j")
(dfm1 <- dfm(txt1))
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 7 features (28.6% sparse).
# 2 x 7 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs a b c f g h d
#   d1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0
#   d2 2 0 2 3 0 0 1

(dfm2 <- dfm(txt2))
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 8 features (43.8% sparse).
# 2 x 8 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs c d f g h b i j
#   d1 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0
#   d2 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1

impVariables <- c("a", "c", "e", "z")
```

**First Method: Create a dfm and select on that using `dfm_select()`**

Here, we are creating a dfm from the character vector of your features, just so that we register them as features, because of the way that `dfm_select()` works when the selection object is a dfm.

```
impVariablesDfm <- dfm(paste(impVariables, collapse = " "))
dfm_select(dfm1, impVariablesDfm)
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (50% sparse).
# 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs a c e z
#   d1 1 1 0 0
#   d2 2 2 0 0

dfm_select(dfm2, impVariablesDfm)
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (87.5% sparse).
# 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs a c e z
#   d1 0 2 0 0
#   d2 0 0 0 0
```

**Second Method: Create a dictionary and select on that using `dfm_lookup()`**

Let's create a helper function to create a dictionary from a character vector:

```
# make a dictionary where each key = its value
char2dictionary <- function(x) {
    result <- as.list(x)  # make the vector into a list
    names(result) <- x
    dictionary(result)
}
```

Now using dfm lookup, we get only the keys, even ones that were not observed:

```
dfm_lookup(dfm1, dictionary = char2dictionary(impVariables))
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (50% sparse).
# 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs a c e z
#   d1 1 1 0 0
#   d2 2 2 0 0

dfm_lookup(dfm2, dictionary = char2dictionary(impVariables))
# Document-feature matrix of: 2 documents, 4 features (87.5% sparse).
# 2 x 4 sparse Matrix of class "dfmSparse"
#     features
# docs a c e z
#   d1 0 2 0 0
#   d2 0 0 0 0
```

Note: (but the first one at least will work with v0.9.9.65):

```
packageVersion("quanteda")
# [1] ‘0.9.9.85’
```

Comment: Dear @KenBenoit it works sweet, but I run toks on two sets and I need to have exactly the same impVariables in two sets. How to make token_select the same fieatures, keep empty features if they do not show up in the second set? Can I achieve it somehow by changing the order of this syntax or by adding an option? I could not find it in tokens_select.

Comment: Hope that solves it. I edited the title of your question a bit since I think it more accurately reflects what you are asking (which is a very common question!).

Comment: I used impVariablesDfm <- dfm(paste(impVariables, collapse = " ")) and then dfm_select(features = impVariablesDfm) from your answer to achieve the same variables in testing and learning. Random forest worked on new data. I need now to study and describe the syntax carefully. It is a great thing. I am learning better from your answer than anywhere else. I am non'it and studied linguistics when computers were expensive novelty one waited for in a line in uni lab. Thanks so much.